# problems running the script in img

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a SPA with html, css and vanilla JS (I have very little idea of JS). The problem I have is that the method I am using, works correctly in my header where I have only "a" with text inside. But when I want to use an img as "a", the script does not work inside the img, it only allows me to click around the img and not inside it.
I appreciate any help.
This is my script and my html in the part where I have the problem.

```js
const route = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();
  window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
  handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
  404: "./pages/404.html",
  "/": "./pages/index.html",
  "/vehicles": "./pages/vehicles.html",
  "/services": "./pages/services.html",
  "/contact": "./pages/contact.html",
  "/financing": "./pages/financing.html",
  "/locations": "./pages/locations.html",
};

const handleLocation = async () => {
  const path = window.location.pathname;
  const route = routes[path] || routes[404];
  const html = await fetch(route).then((data) => data.text());
  document.getElementById("main-page").innerHTML = html;
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;

handleLocation();
```

```html
<a href="/financing" onclick="route()" class="mainServices-section">                        
  <div class="main-title">
    <h2>Financing</h2>
  </div>
  <img src="../image/financing-image-colored.svg" alt="">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you click the `<img>` the `target` isn't set to your `<a>` tag so `event.target.href` is `undefined`.

Instead of using `onclick` attributes, use a delegated event listener and check if it originates from an `<a>` tag or a descendant.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const anchor = e.target.closest("a[href]");
  if (anchor) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState({}, "", anchor.href);
    handleLocation();
  }
});
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/dgn1r5zh/

Answer (score 1):

This behavior happens because `event.target` is a reference to the element that fired the event. In this case that is your image.

First of let me point out that inline event handlers should not be used. They can create unexpected behavior and make you write JS inside HTML. [More about this topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). Learn to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

You can fix your issue by adding some CSS to your element that you want to click. With CSS the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) you can determine if an element should be able to become a [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Implement this by selecting all the elements within the element that you want to have as your target and set `pointer-events: none;` to disable any pointer events on those elements. This ensures that the `<a>` tag is the only element that can be considered a `target`. So `event.target` in your code will always point to the correct element.

```
.mainServices-section * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Alternatively, if you can't use `pointer-events` because, for example you need some other pointer event to fire on the children of `.mainServices-section`, then you should extend your code by explicitly checking if the current target is the `<a>` tag and otherwise select the `<a>` tag if possible.

You can search for the `<a>` from any child within the element with the [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) that is on the clicked element. It walks up and looks for the element that you're searching for.

```
const route = (event) => {
  const target = event.target.closest('.mainServices-section');
  if (target === null) {
    return;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
  window.history.pushState({}, "", target.href);
  handleLocation();
};

const mainServicesSections = document.querySelectorAll('.mainServices-section');
for (const mainServiceSection of mainServicesSections) {
  mainServiceSection.addEventListener('click', route);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it worked correctly. But in a section of the web, I need a contact form, that through javascript open the Email app and pre fill the corresponding fields. And somehow this script interferes in the operation. I leave you the link to the question so you can see it if you can, since I can not explain it in the comment with the character limit. I would appreciate it if you could give me a hand with that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74736445/problems-with-scripts-in-a-spa

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for the `.closest("a")` of the clicked element `ev.target`:

```js
var hist="none";
const route = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();
  hist=event.target.closest("a").getAttribute("href");
  handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
  404: "./pages/404.html",
  "/": "./pages/index.html",
  "/vehicles": "./pages/vehicles.html",
  "/services": "./pages/services.html",
  "/contact": "./pages/contact.html",
  "/financing": "./pages/financing.html",
  "/locations": "./pages/locations.html",
};

const handleLocation = async () => {
  const route = routes[hist] || routes[404];
  console.log(route);
  // fetch() etc. to be placed here ...
};

// window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
// window.route = route;

handleLocation();
```

```html
<a href="/financing" onclick="route()" class="mainServices-section">                        
  <div class="main-title">
<h2>Financing</h2>
  </div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
</a>
```

Another thing I changed is the way to look for the `href` attribute of the `<a>` element: `DOMelement.href` will return an absolute path, starting with "https://" while `DOMelement.getAttribute("href")` will actually get you the string as defined in the element's attribute.