# Problems with scripts in a SPA

Tags: javascript, forms, single-page-application

This is the script I am using to create a spa.

```
const route = (event) => {
  event = event || window.event;
  event.preventDefault();
  window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
  handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
  404: "./pages/404.html",
  "/": "./pages/index.html",
  "/vehicles": "./pages/vehicles.html",
  "/services": "./pages/services.html",
  "/contact": "./pages/contact.html",
  "/financing": "./pages/financing.html",
  "/locations": "./pages/locations.html",
};

const handleLocation = async () => {
  const path = window.location.pathname;
  const route = routes[path] || routes[404];
  const html = await fetch(route).then((data) => data.text());
  document.getElementById("main-page").innerHTML = html;
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;

handleLocation();
<a href="/financing" onclick="route()" class="mainServices-section">                        
  <div class="main-title">
    <h2>Financing</h2>
  </div>
  <img src="../image/financing-image-colored.svg" alt="">
</a>
```

It worked correctly for me. But in a section of the web, I need a contact form, which through javascript open the Email app and pre complete the corresponding fields.

```
        <section class="contact inset-wrapper">
            <form class="form content" id="form" action="">
                <h2 class="title"><strong>let's talk</strong></h2>
                <h4 class="subtitle">Do not hesitate to contact us for more information about the vehicle you are interested in.</h4>        
                <label for="name">
                    <h4>Name</h4>
                </label>
                    <input required name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Juan Lucas López">
                <label for="email">
                    <h4>Email</h4>
                </label>
                    <input required name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <label for="message">
                    <h4>Message</h4>
                </label>
                    <textarea required name="message" placeholder="Message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <button class="form-button" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                <a id="sendMail" href="mailto:mauriciolaratro@gmail.com" ></a>
            </form>
        </section>

        <script>
            const $form = document.querySelector('#form')
            const $buttonMailto = document.querySelector('#sendMail')

            $form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit)

            function handleSubmit(event) {
                event.preventDefault()
                const form = new FormData(this)
                $buttonMailto.setAttribute('href', `mailto:mauriciolaratro@gmail.com?subjet=${form.get('name')} ${form.get('email')}&body=${form.get('message')}`)
                $buttonMailto.click()
            }
        </script>
```

This is the code I use to make the form, which works perfectly, when I use it in another project, however, the previous script interferes with this somehow and I do not know how to fix it (Again I clarify that I am new to js).
What happens is that instead of redirecting to the Email app, it tries to redirect the web to a non-existent link.
I would appreciate any contribution, to be able to solve this in the simplest way, I am trying to make this project, without consuming external API, I know that there are simpler and more efficient ways to make the form functional, but the idea is to do everything with vanilla code and without API